# Change javascript object key to property value

Tags: javascript

I have two variable like this, one is array of objects and one is object of objects

```
let state_checklist = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Q1',
    question_id: 'CuaQV',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Q3',
    question_id: 'XKVbQ',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Q2',
    question_id: 'zmId1',
  },
];

let state_question = {
  2: { answer: 'yes', comments: '', question_id: 'CuaQV' },
  3: { answer: 'no', comments: '', question_id: 'zmId1' },
};
```

Now I want to create a structure like this

```
{
    "zmId1": {
        "answer": "yes",
        "comments": "",
        "question_id": "zmId1",
        "title": "Q2"
    },
    "CuaQV": {
        "answer": "no",
        "comments": "",
        "question_id": "CuaQV",
        "title": "Q1"
    }
}
```

where key should be question_id

Code that I have tried to generate that object is below, here I am unable to create the question_id as key, else everything is seems ok for me.

```
//var obj = {};
for (var key in state_question) {
  if (state_question.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    //var key = state_question[key]['question_id'];
    const questionid = state_question[key]['question_id'];
    const title = state_checklist.find(
      (q) => q.question_id == questionid
    ).title;
    state_question[key]['title'] = title;
    //obj[key] = state_question[key];
    console.log(title);
  }
}

console.log(state_question);
```

Comment: I think you should give more detail on the Data Structure and intent of your code.

Comment: is your sample correct? `state_question` zmId1 - answer - no, expected result, answer is yes.

Comment: Ya and the answer that was given is seems ok to me. I was trying to implement something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through your checklist and then map the values to an object and look up the other object array values with what exist there and missed in your result

```
const questions = {};
for (const q of state_checklist) {
   const answerFound = Object.values(state_question).find(x => q.question_id === x.question_id);
   if (answerFound) {
      questions[q.question_id] = {
         question_id: q.question_id,
         title: q.title,
         answer: answerFound.answer,
         comments: answerFound.comments
      }
   }
}

// Result
// { CuaQV: { question_id: 'CuaQV', title: 'Q1', answer: 'yes', comments: '' },
//   zmId1: { question_id: 'zmId1', title: 'Q2', answer: 'no', comments: '' } 
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically a shorter answer to use `reduce` function of Array produced by `Object.values(state_question)`, and compose the object (starting with `{}`) as below:

```js
const result = Object.values(state_question).reduce((acc, val) => ({
        ...acc,
        [val.question_id]: {
          // ...state_checklist.find(item => item.question_id === val.question_id),
          title: state_checklist.find(item => item.question_id === val.question_id).title,
          ...val,
        }
    }), {});

console.log(result);

// { CuaQV: { question_id: 'CuaQV', title: 'Q1', answer: 'yes', comments: '' },
//   zmId1: { question_id: 'zmId1', title: 'Q2', answer: 'no', comments: '' } 
// }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).